# Вращение в направлении объекта лишь по одной оси. [Unity C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d, геометрия

Есть пушка и есть цель. При этом основание и сама пушка вращаются отдельно, основание управляет азимутом, в то время как пушка - склонением. Каким образом я могу сделать так, чтобы основание наводилось на цель, которая не находится на плоскости вращения основания? То есть крутить до тех пор, пока основание не будет направлено просто в сторону цели. Пока код такой, но он просто крутит основание по кругу:

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Vector3.Normalize(target.transform.position - transform.position).y * 100, 0), Space.Self);
```

Comment: Постройте вектор из центра основания на цель, высчитайте его проекцию на плоскость вращения основания. Высчитайте проекцию вектора ствола пушки на плоскость вращения основания. Вращайте основание до тех пор, пока эти проекции не совпадут. Для простоты сравнения проекций можно обе привести к единичной длине.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public GameObject Target;
float Speed = 30f; // градусы в секунду

void Update () {
    // находим угол цели через арктангенс и конвертируем радианы в градусы
    float Angle = -Mathf.Atan2(Target.transform.position.z-transform.position.z, Target.transform.position.x-transform.position.x)/Mathf.PI*180f;
    // градус поворота
    float RotAng = Speed*Time.deltaTime;
    // градус между поворотом объекта и углом цели
    float DeltaAng = Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, Angle);
    if (Mathf.Abs(DeltaAng) < RotAng) {
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, Angle, transform.eulerAngles.z);
    } else {
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, RotAng*Mathf.Sign(DeltaAng), 0);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот код странно работает, он куда-то мимо целится, а в один момент так и вообще его колбасить начинает. Возможно, это из-за особенностей расположения турели(повернута по оси Z на 10 градусов). Но что бы я не делал, точного наведения на цель я не увидел.

Comment: Код не "странный", он "рабочий"! Видимо вы не верно задали вопрос или описали вашу ситуацию. Пушка на скриншотах повёрнута по оси Z на 10 градусов и это никак её не мешает.